# thread lock object in properties get/set

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

When using locks, do I need to lock around my get? From my testing I do not need to do so, but I wanted to make sure. Also, how do I format the code I posted so it has the proper schema colors? It is asking me to add more details, but I don't really know what to add- I am moreover asking (from someone more experienced than I) if what I have is correct and will work without throwing cross thread exceptions.

```
class exam
{
    private static readonly exam x = new exam();
    private static readonly object lckobj = new object();

    private int i;
    private int _count;

    private exam() { }

    public static exam AccessPoint
    {
        get
        {
            return x;
        }
    }

    public int myInt
    {
        get
        {
            return i;
        }
        set
        {
            lock(lckobj)
            {
                i = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return _count;
        }
        set
        {
            lock(lckobj)
            {
                _count = value;
            }
        }
    }

}

class myDemo
{
    Random r = new Random();
    bool b = false;
    Thread[] t = new Thread[3];

    public myDemo()
    {
        for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            t[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(thread1));
            t[i].Start();
        }

        Thread checks = new Thread(new ThreadStart(checkB));
        checks.Start();

    }

    void checkB()
    {
        var x = exam.AccessPoint;
        while (!b)
        {
            b = (x.Count >= 10) ? true : false;
            Console.WriteLine("\tb:{0}\tCount:{1}", b, x.Count);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    void thread1()
    {
        var x = exam.AccessPoint;

        while (!b)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(r.Next(500, 1000));

            x.myInt = r.Next(1, 10);
            x.Count = x.Count + 1;
            Console.WriteLine(x.myInt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes sorry C#- I never know whether or not to add tag of C#

Comment: @EricLippert has a great read on the subject. He looks at the question "Should i lock when only reading an int" http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/12/can-i-skip-the-lock-when-reading-an-integer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even *if* you added the lock around the `get` your code *still* wouldn't work properly, although there are more possible things that can go wrong if you don't do that.

The following line is problematic in a way that cannot be fixed by locking in `Count`:

```
x.Count = x.Count + 1;
```

Here even if you add locks, it's entirely possible for one thread to read a value, stop before updating, then have another thread read the value, increment the count, and then write it back.  That write will be overridden when the first thread continues on.  No amount of locking in `Count` will change that.

Of course, without the `lock` in `Count` there is no memory barrier introduced, so reads to that value are allowed to be reading stale values, which can further exacerbate the previous problem.

Comment: the above code is an example of different code that will not normally have that issue- I'm not asking for a logic check as in will it stop correctly where it is supposed to- I am curious as to whether or not I need locks around my get to ensure thread safety *the real code is thousands of lines and multiple classes- I just need to know if I have multiple threads accessing a get on my static class if it will throw cross thread exception- the above code works without any of those errors so I think* it is okay, but wanted verification.

Comment: @user3198872 Thread safety is a function of an entire program, not individual operations.  A sequence of individually atomic operations can be combined in ways that make the entire program not function as would be desired.  Without knowing how a given method is going to be used one cannot analyze if it is sufficently "safe" for the purposes of its callers.  See [this blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx) for further information.  Here's [another article](http://blog.coverity.com/2014/03/12/) if you're interested.

Comment: I feel everyone is getting hung up on the count logic- that does not matter- it was simply a way for me to build in a dead-kill so my void threads did not go on for an infinite amount of time.

Comment: @user3198872 But *it does matter*.  It is of the utmost importance.  Your claim that it is irrelevant is false.  How you plan to use this type is essential to how it should be implemented.  If you want to know if an implementation should be performed, we need to know what you plan to do with it.

Comment: Sorry I had to add another comment due to length...

I also read article 2 you linked and it makes things more confusing- I understand what it's saying about locking around the get in that it cannot read before/after the lock was imposed, but what about if the set is locked? If the property is being read via an unlocked get, then how can a set with a lock impose a lock around that object? or would that right there be the cross talk exception? and if so- why when I run the above code do I not get any exceptions?

Comment: I completely get what you are saying, and I agree- without knowing implementation it wouldn't matter... But all I need know is if I have to lock around my get{}... I have the code working in place- it never throws an exception- I need to know if I have it right or am just getting lucky. I only need to know if I need to lock around a get. The point is being missed. I couldn't ask "when locking do I need to lock around a get{}" without an example- and now that example is being analyzed instead of the theory question.

Comment: @user3198872 Code that has race conditions in it; that is code not properly designed to work in multiple threads, is *highly* difficult to debug.  You generally won't have it throw an exception every time it runs.  It might work 50% of the time.  It might even work 99 or 99.99% of the time, but that doesn't make it correct, or mean that it *will* work properly.  And when it doesn't work all sorts of problems can happen, ranging form exceptions, to program crashes, to bad data, to lost data, and all sorts of other options.

Comment: @user3198872 You need to stop asking yourself if you should lock around the getter/setter of your property.  **That is the wrong question to ask**.  You should be asking what your entire program needs to do, in what ways different threads will interact, and how you can synchronize those interactions in ways that result in the program functioning.  Perhaps that means locking around a property getter, perhaps not.  The proper way of synchronizing a program can only be discussed when we see that program.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51700/discussion-between-user3198872-and-servy)

Comment: answered in chat- complicated answer. See chat for details
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/51700

Answer (score 1):

Reading a value of a variable by multiple threads in the same time is safe.
Writing a value to a variable by multiple threads in the same time is **not safe**.
Writing a value to a variable by one thread in the same time as one ore more threads are reading from this variable is **not safe**.

So using the same lock in both setter and getter is required.
Problem described in @Servy answer requires a better solution though. Any flavour of locking mechanism which wraps so called "SELECT FOR UPDATE" (I know this goes for DB but the problem is the same) should be good enough.

You should even reuse the same lock you already have in your code. Make it `public` since it's `readonly` and for such situations use it from outside:

```
lock(exam.lckobj){
    exam.myInt = exam.myInt + 1;
}
```

Comment: thanks- that's what I needed to know.
edit: wait- don't these statements contradict each other?

"Reading a value of a variable by multiple threads in the same time is safe."

"Reading a value of a variable by one thread in the same time as one ore more threads are reading from this variable is not safe."

Comment: Fixed typos - now it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

For integer values use Interlocked.Read and Interlock.Exchange. Very atomic, very thread safe, doesn't carry the weight of a mutex (via lock).

Comment: Just using an atomic read/write does not make a program thread safe.  In fact, the example program *wouldn't* be thread safe just by using these methods in the properties getter/setter.

Comment: @Servy If the getter is get { return Interlocked.Read(ref foo); } and the setter is set { Interlocked.Exchange(ref foo, value); } how is that not atomic and therefore thread safe?

Comment: It is atomic, but just because that one operation is atomic then that doesn't make the entire program thread safe.  Let's say that the property represents an `int`.  If someone writes `foo.ThatIntProperty++;` while another thread is doing the same thing in another thread, the program is not going to function properly.  If the property returns a reference to a mutable reference type, say a `List`, and that object is mutated from one thread while another is reading from it, all sorts of badness can happen.

Comment: @Servy While I don't disagree that bad habits create bad code, if Interlocked is used to access the variable (and I did specifically say integer value, though any base value type if fine really) use of Interlocked is 100% thread safe and an order of magnitude more efficient than use of lock or a WaitHandle.

Comment: No, it's not safe.  I just provided an example of a completely broken program that uses your implementation of a property.  it is not safe in the least.  Making the property getter/setter atomic in no way guarantees that the program will function properly.  Making your program more efficient is *irrelevant* when *it doesn't work*.

Comment: @Servy I'm fairly certain you do not understand the articles your referring to. Interlocked is the definition of thread safe, wait handles (all that locking and mutex stuff) is based on it. I just re-re-tested using Interlocked in a getter / setting and it exactly what you need (and no more) for managing access to a single private integer value. Yes if the memory is access without use of Interlocked, the thread safety is gone, but it's a private and the developer should know better.

Comment: In what way do I not understand what I'm referring to?  By all means, explain how it's impossible for a single atomic operation to be used to create a program that doesn't behave as expected.  I'm all ears.  I have *already* shown you a trivially easy to write case of a program that takes your code and is entirely and fundamentally broken.  Your "solution" in *no way whatsoever* solves the problem you claim it does.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51767/discussion-between-focuspark-and-servy)